# Excel macro loop cell value need to change according to the loop

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a sheet automatically created, depend on some condition I need to read the values on the column A, check with another sheet whether it exists , and print "Yes" or "No" on column D. The formula in column D is:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A4,proj_req!F:F,0)),""No"",""Yes"")
```

How can I create a loop stmt so that column D has the above formula, i.e

```
Do While current_Row < lastRow
ThisWorkbook. Sheets("features").Range("D" & current_Row).formula ="=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A4,proj_req!F:F,0)),""No"",""Yes"")"
current_Row = current_Row + 1
Loop
```

inside MATCH(A should have the same row as the D current_Row)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Do While current_Row < lastRow
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("features").Range("D" & current_Row).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A" & current_Row & ",proj_req!F:F,0)),""No"",""Yes"")"
    current_Row = current_Row + 1
Loop
```